# Facebook comments with identification number

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I want to use the facebook comments in my site. I have many people page `index.php?id=...`
I need to define each people page its comments block. Standard code from facebook, gives me one comment block to all pages.

How can I add identification the people page by dint of his `id` from `GET`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the users have a unique id that won't change, then you can use the href parameter when invoking the comments and pass the url with the id= being dynamic.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Answer (score 0):

Use the data-href attribute and add your URL here.

For instance, you can do something like this in php:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

echo '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://index.com/$id" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>'
```